# Regex - Match entire selection

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which I'd like to test against a regex that will detect if there's any matches, and then deletes them out of the string.

I'd like to match pattern such as

```
&#55357;
&#12931;
```

Anything that starts with &# followed by 5 random digits, ending with a ;

Currently I've came up with this:

```
([&#\d;])
```

Which works, but it also selects single occurences of a digit or &, #

What kind of adjustments should I make to only select occurences that matches the pattern I described?

Comment: Try this `([&#\d{5};])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `&#\d{5};`

**\d{5} :** Any digit, exactly 5 repeatitions

If you want to detect end of line, you can use `$` and also `^` for the string start position.

Thanks [@xxxvodnikxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892907/xxxvodnikxxx)

Comment: and also ^ for the string start position

Answer (score 4):

Since the string has a precise format, the regex should be:

`&#\d{5};`

- this will match the digits precisely 5 times (not more, not less).
- also, you don't need Character Classes `[]` since, the positions of each character are strict.
- You can add a capturing group if necessary, `(&#\d{5};)` - if not, leave it out.
- Additionally, you do not need `^` and `$` if you know you data will always be of the format you have show. The regex engine will have to perform 2 additional steps if you add `^regex$`. It's a micropotimization, but if you are processing a lot of data, it might save you a bit of time. Compare the step count in these two examples:

[image]

and

[image]

With regex in general you want to be precise and specific.